# How to set rest values based on default checkbox using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i am using Angular8 with Bootstrap, here i have used reactive forms, when i check on `Make Default` checkbox, then values present in `Flowers` row (Mail, Electronic,Delivery and Receipent)should be copied same to rest rows.

If the fax number format is not proper, how to show error message just below particular row recepient.

Ts:

```
 checkAll(ev) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.exampleForm.get("printList");
    if (!this.all) {
      this.printListArray.forEach(x => (x.value = false));
      control.patchValue(this.printListArray);
    } else {
      this.printListArray.forEach(x => (x.value = true));
      control.patchValue(this.printListArray);
    }
    console.log(control.value);
  }

  isAllChecked() {
    this.all = !this.all;
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5utc3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work more like the following

```js
  checkAll(ev) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.exampleForm.get("printList");
    console.log(this.all);
    if (this.all) {
      this.all = false;
      this.printListArray.forEach(x => (x.electronics = false));
      control.patchValue(this.printListArray);
    } else {
      this.all = true;
      this.printListArray.forEach(x => (x.electronics = true));
      control.patchValue(this.printListArray);
    }
  }
```

The main difference is that instead of changing the `value` field of `x` I'm changing the `electronics` fields, so when you are patching the form latter on, `this.printListArray` will have the appropriate data in the appropriate state.

In the implementation that I'm suggesting you will be able to toggle all `checboxes` in the row `Electronics`

Keep in mind that the `printListArray` is not an array form `FormGroup/FormControl`, its an array of regular objects, so the field `value` that usually exists in the `FormControl` is not present.

Comment: Thanks for response, but sorry i am not able to run output

Comment: What do you mean by run output?

Comment: Try this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-checkbox-question?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I tried this link, but my requirement is different, in the first row, (Flowers row), we have mail, electronics, Delivery dropdown, Recepient, when Make Default is checked, what mail value, electronic value, delivery dropdown value, recepient value is present for Flowers row, should be copied to all rows, something like If selected, copy the field values (check boxes, drop down, and text box) to all other rows.

Comment: Check the link again, i've made it so that whenever you click the "Make the same as firt rows" button the value from the first row will be applied across the rest of the rows, the logic is the same as with the checkboxes, the only difference is that here im updating the form itself instead the array of elements

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but if there is error in fax number, can error message be showed just below the recepient of that row?

Comment: i will vote this answer and accept, please help me with the other validation one commented above please

Comment: What is the desired fax number validation?

Comment: Ng-mask I have used, and it must have prefix +1 (456) 987-6788

Comment: If email is choosen, the receipient should have email validation, if fax means fax validation, wanna try for both, tried but couldn’t make it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66898640/how-to-show-validation-error-for-each-row-for-email-and-fax-for-loop-items-using please help me with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230627/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and--).