# How to show validation error for each row for email and fax for loop items using angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular8 with bootstrap. I have made inputs from a loop array. If there is any validation error for email or fax number, it is throwing validation error. Then, if there is an error for the email field in the first row, if there is any error for fax in second row it shows. if in the 3rd row if email is entered incorrectly and then corrected, the first row validation error also goes off.

I want to show validation error for all rows of there is an error with respect to fax or email fields.

HTML:

```
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="Recepient"
                          formControlName="recipients" *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId == 178"
                          (focusout)="validationErrorOnFocusOut('emailvalid',data)"
                          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': emailsubmitted  && data.controls.recipients.errors}"
                          pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" autocomplete="off">
              <div *ngIf="(emailsubmitted && data.controls.recipients.errors)" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="(emailsubmitted && data.controls.recipients.errors)">
                  Please enter valid email</div>
              </div>
              <input type='text' prefix="+1 " mask=" (000) 000-0000" class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Recepient" name="Recepient" formControlName="recipients"
                          *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId == 179" maxLength="18"
                          (focusout)="validationErrorOnFocusOut('fax',data)"
                          autocomplete="off"
                          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid':faxsubmitted && data.controls.recipients.errors.mask}">
              <div *ngIf="faxsubmitted && data.controls.recipients.errors.mask" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="faxsubmitted && data.controls.recipients.errors.mask">Please enter valid fax number
                </div>
              </div>
```

TS:

```
  public validationErrorOnFocusOut(name, data) {
    if (name == "emailvalid") {
      if (data.controls.recipients.status === "VALID") {
        this.emailsubmitted = false;
      } else {
        this.emailsubmitted = true;
      }
      if (
        data.controls.recipients.value === "" ||
        data.controls.recipients.value === null
      ) {
        this.emailsubmitted = false;
      }
    } else if (name == "fax") {
      if (data.controls.recipients.status === "VALID") {
        this.faxsubmitted = false;
      } else {
        this.faxsubmitted = true;
      }
      if (
        data.controls.recipients.value === "" ||
        data.controls.recipients.value === null
      ) {
        this.faxsubmitted = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-jpdrka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Thanks for response, my issue is that, when there is b;ur out, i need to show validation error message inline, so here, 1st i  choosed delivery as email and gave wrong email format, it showed validation error, 2nd i took fax and gave wrong pattern it throwed validation error, then 3rd i gave email as delivery and gave wrong pattern, it showed validation and when i corrected email in 3rd row, 1st row error also went off, this is my issue, this is same for fax and email as well

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use html5 validation? Unless I am overlooking some unusual requirement, it will do exactly what you need, and with a lot less code/markup. Just change your input types (from 'text' to 'email' etc.)

Comment: Also, why did you add classes for the widths in your app.component.css? Just adding `"width="xx"` is smaller than `class="widthxx"` . Are you changing class dynamically somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set up your form correctly using the `FormBuilder`. My Solution will focus on the `Reactivity` of your form

Below are the steps I have taken

1. Remove the binding on `[disabled]` property https://stackoverflow.com/a/58831653/13680115
   Below is a warning in the console thrown if you do include `[disabled]` property

```
It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

Example:
form = new FormGroup({
first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
});
```

2. Remove the `onChange` event handler. In its place we will have below in our `ngOninit` function. We will watch for form valuechanges and react to this to disable the appropriate  control

```typescript
      this.printListControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap((controls: any[]) => {
          controls.forEach(({ mail, deliveryMethodId }, index) => {
            const control = this.printListControl.at(index);

            if (mail) {
              control.get("deliveryMethodId").enable({ emitEvent: false });
              control.get("recipients").enable({ emitEvent: false });
            } else {
              // I would not include below two lines for better user experience.
              control
                .get("deliveryMethodId")
                .setValue(null, { emitEvent: false });
              control.get("recipients").setValue(null, { emitEvent: false });

              control.get("deliveryMethodId").disable({ emitEvent: false });
              control.get("recipients").disable({ emitEvent: false });
            }

            // console.log(deliveryMethodId);

            control
              .get("recipients")
              .setValidators(this.getRecipientsValidation(deliveryMethodId));
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
  getRecipientsValidation(deliveryMethodId) {
    return +deliveryMethodId === 178
      ? [Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern), Validators.required]
      : +deliveryMethodId === 179
      ? [
          Validators.minLength(10),
            (10),
          Validators.required
        ]
      : [Validators.required];
  }
```

Now whenever the `mail` value is changed the `deliveryMethodId` and `recipients` control are enabled or disabled

Also we update the validators based on the delivery method selected

2. Remove the pattern validations from the html. We will use `Validators.pattern`

We can declare the patterns

```
emailPattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
```

3. Remove the event for `validationErrorOnFocusOut` from the template
4. Since we have removed the template validation, we can employ the use of `Validator` static classes

```typescript
    let printList = this.printListArray.map(x => {
      const { deliveryMethodId } = x;
      return this.fb.group({
        id: x.id,
        name: x.name,
        mail: x.mail,
        electronics: x.electronics,
        deliveryMethodId: x.deliveryMethodId,
        recipients: [
          x.recipients,
          {
            validators:
              deliveryMethodId === 178
                ? [Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern), Validators.required]
                : deliveryMethodId === 179
                ? [
                    Validators.minLength(10),
                    Validators.maxLength(10),
                    Validators.required
                  ]
                : [Validators.required],
            updateOn: "blur"
          }
        ]
      });
    });
```

We are applying validation to each control individally to avoid their effect on other controls

4. Finally our html will be something like this

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"
     *ngFor="let data of exampleForm.get('printList').controls; let j = index" formArrayName="printList">
  <div [formGroupName]="j">
    <table class="table table-print table-borderless">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row" class="width90">{{data.value.name}}</td>

        <td class="width50">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="mail"
            formControlName="mail"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="width50">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="electronics"
            formControlName="electronics"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="width100">

          <select
            class="custom-select"
            formControlName="deliveryMethodId"
            name="deliveryMethodId"
            tabindex="1" (change)="dropdownSelection(j)"
          >
            <option value=null>Select One </option>
            <option
              *ngFor="let agencyType of DeliveryMethod"
              [value]="agencyType.id"
            >
              {{agencyType.label}}</option
            >
          </select>
        </td>
        <td class="width200">
          <ng-container *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId == 178">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="Recepient"
                   formControlName="recipients" *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId == 178"
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': data.get('recipients').invalid && data.get('recipients').touched }"
                   autocomplete="off">

            <div class='invalid-feedback' *ngIf="data.get('recipients').invalid">
              Please enter valid email
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId == 179">
            <input type="text"  prefix="+1 " class="form-control" placeholder="(###) ### - ####"
                   formControlName="recipients" name="recipients" autocomplete="off"
                   *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId == 179"
                   mask=" (000) 000-0000" [showMaskTyped]="false"
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid' : data.get('recipients').invalid && data.get('recipients').touched }" >

            <div class='invalid-feedback'>
              Please enter valid fax number
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="data.value.deliveryMethodId != '178' && data.value.deliveryMethodId != '179'">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recepient" name="Recepient"
                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid' : data.get('recipients').invalid && data.get('recipients').touched }"
                   formControlName="recipients"
            />
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>
              Field is required
            </div>
          </ng-container>


        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-kayngz)

Comment: Thanks for response, will update you once I test in the morning

Comment: Hi i tried, but here in the 1st input i gave email as wrong, and 2nd fax as wrong, then 3rd email as wrong again but it didnt show me validation error, and 4th i gave proper fax number but still its showing validation error as well

Comment: Ya please, Thank you

Comment: Please check, was an issue with types mismatch when checking the selected item. I had to add `+` to change string to integer. Now it works, please confirm

Comment: i tried its working, but when we gave proper pattern then the error must go off even without focus out

Comment: also, for example, i have choosed email and gave proper validation, but when i change that from fax to email or to others it says filed is required

Comment: i have tried upto here, in this demo link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-4qg6sv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html but only missed thing is, when we see validation error, and if the email or fax format is correct it stil shows the error until and unless i focusout, the error message doesnt go

Comment: also if there is still error message with the input fields and if i try to save, it must throw me alert message, if al goof it must say, alert saying success

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong in any of the ways, and help me to make functionality work as expected, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-4qg6sv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: A major problem mistake you are doing is changing values in the view after they have been checked. If you check the console of your code you will see `expression changed after it was checked` errors.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-1rzhxw

Comment: Thanks for response, but only issue is when i start typing the validation error message is shown, but i want validation message to be shown during focus out, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-uszysd

Comment: and one more issue, if the electronics is checked, then delivery and recipents to be enabled, if it is unchecked then delivery and recipeints to be disabled, even that is not working, please check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230739/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-owen-kelvin).